# 100 equals to1 minute in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

My Database:

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKAhT.png)

When I need End Time to be +10secs from now I execute:

```
INSERT INTO `record` (`End_Time`) VALUES (now() + 10);
```

Result:

[Result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EoW1.png)

When I need End Time to be +10 min from now I execute:

```
INSERT INTO `record` (`End_Time`) VALUES (now() + 600);
```

Result:

[Result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erXVB.png)

> **It added only 6 mins from now and not 10!**

Does this mean as per SQL 100 seconds equals to 1 minute? (If yes, this will make lots of confusion)

Result:

Comment: now() means now not Start_Time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax.  You want to use `interval`:

```
VALUES (now() + interval 10 second)
```

MySQL gets a bit confused about `+`.  Without `interval` it treats the values as big integers, in the format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS -- so you get the results you are seeing.  With `interval` it knows that you want `+` to add date/time values.

You could also use `date_add()`.

Comment: So, to add 10 mins it should be: `VALUES (now() + interval 10 minute)`?

Comment: @yevoboc . . . Yes.